# Animate elements with opacity

Tags: html, css, css-animations

There is such HTML code:

```
<p class="logo">m
  <span class="blink">y</span>
   Po
  <span class="blink">r</span>
   tf
  <span class="blink">o</span>
   lio
</p>
```

Here is his styling:

```
.logo {
 position: relative;
 cursor: default;
 font: 400 4em 'flottflottregular';
 color: #fee;
 text-shadow: 0 -40px 100px, 0 0 2px, 0 0 1em #ffff00, 0 0 0.5em #ffff00, 0 0 0.1em #ffff00, 0 15px 
    5px #000;
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result]
When I try to animate individual letters using opacity (applying animation to the .blink class):

```
0%    {opacity: 1;}
3%    {opacity: 0.4;}
6%    {opacity: 1;}
7%    {opacity: 0.4;}
8%    {opacity: 1;}
9%    {opacity: 0.4;}
10%   {opacity: 1;}
89%   {opacity: 1;}
90%   {opacity: 0.4;}
100%  {opacity: 0.4;}
```

it turns out that the animated elements have a more saturated shadow compared to other letters:
[image: Result with animation]

How to fix this effect?

I also tried to animate with text-shadow changing, but 
it is difficult for the browser to handle this effect and animation have low FPS:

```
78% {
color: inherit;
text-shadow: inherit;
}
79% {
color: #333;
}
80% {
text-shadow: none;
}
81% {
color: inherit;
text-shadow: inherit;
}
82% {
color: #333;
text-shadow: none;
}
83% {
color: inherit;
text-shadow: inherit;
}
92% {
color: #333;
text-shadow: none;
}
92.5% {
color: inherit;
text-shadow: inherit;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to get

Comment: I'm trying to make a neon blink

Comment: can you make a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What browser are you using? I don't see the saturation behavior you're describing in Chrome or Safari. (https://codepen.io/apexskier/pen/QWjbNJM)

Comment: here it is on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0cv1ydf3/1/

Comment: i'm using Chrome